# Why is the format of the sql files affecting if they can run or not in PG?

Tags: postgresql, docker, psql

I have placed a file in my `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` directory.  Here is what is in the file:

```
CREATE TABLE user_test (
    user_id    INTEGER,
    name       VARCHAR(100),
    email      VARCHAR(128),
    active_flg BOOLEAN,
    type       VARCHAR(20),
    CONSTRAINT pk_user PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);
```

The error I am getting is `psql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0001-initial-database-design.sql:8: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CREATE"`.

What am I missing in being able to run a file?  How do I change this file to work?

Comment: Why do you think the error is format related (according to your title)?

Comment: I am getting the error on the word `CREATE`, not anything after it.  That is a valid keyword in pg.  My thought was I had the file formatted in a way that pg couldn't/wouldn't understand.  Maybe even a hidden character.  I can change the name of the table to anything and I get the same error.

Comment: Any chance the file is saved as UTF-8 **with** a [bom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)?

Comment: How can I find that out?

Answer (score 1):

`USER` is a reserved keyword in Postgres, [see the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/sql-keywords-appendix.html).  In general, you should avoid naming your tables and columns using reserved SQL keywords.  If you really wanted to proceed as is, then place `user` into double quotes:

```
CREATE TABLE "user" (
    user_id    INTEGER,
    name       VARCHAR(100),
    email      VARCHAR(128),
    active_flg BOOLEAN,
    type       VARCHAR(20),
    CONSTRAINT pk_user PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);
```

But, keep in mind that if you choose to name your table `user`, then you will forever have to escape it with double quotes.